# recent problem with android_apps (catkin_make)

Tags: catkin-make, android

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had a working environment, for developing android apps for ROS.
today, I opened Android Studio, and at the start it started "refreshing the project" .. and all of the sudden I started getting errors about gradle wrapper..
I fell back to terminal, and tried to reinvoke "catkin_make" on the dir.
and I got this error:

```
* Where:
Build file '/home/aminasfour/project/android/src/android_apps/application_management/build.gradle' line: 26

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':application_management'.
> Could not create plugin of type 'LibraryPlugin'.
```

I've tried to download everything from scratch .. and re-followed this tutorial:
http://wiki.ros.org/sig/Rosjava/Android%20Development%20Environment/hydro.
unfortunately I'm still getting the same error mentioned above.
Please I need advice on how to fix it, I have a project that I need to deliver within a week.
Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/145521/recent-problem-with-android_apps-(catkin_make)/) by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2014-03-27

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-03-27**:
I suspect this is due to a recent change on your system. You could try reviewing the package install logs in /var/log/dpkg if you're on Ubuntu

**Comment by [AMiNAsFour](https://answers.ros.org/users/13311/aminasfour/) on 2014-03-27**:
It's not, the latest update that appears there, dates back to two weeks ago (and it used to work then)

**Comment by [fapofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/9186/fapofa/) on 2014-04-09**:
Try to update the distributionUrl=http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.10-all.zip in the gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties. This solved my problems regarding the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If I recall correctly, I got the same error with the recent android studio/build tools version/gradle android plugin and gradle updates. Some of these are embedded in rosjava_build_tools (sdk version and android gradle plugin), so if you updated rosjava_build_tools on hydro, then it will automatically be trying to use 19.0.3 build tools version and android gradle plugin 0.9.+.

If you want to keep to old unsupported (by android studio) versions, then simply override these variables/dependencies in your local build.gradle files. Otherwise update your android studio/rosjava_build_tools and it should disappear.

For the record, I'm now using (April '14)

- Android 0.5.4
- Build Tools 19.0.3
- Android Gradle Plugin 0.9+
- Gradle 1.11

---

Originally posted by [Daniel Stonier](https://answers.ros.org/users/51/daniel-stonier/) with karma: 3170 on 2014-04-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See this commit which seems to fix this issue:

https://github.com/rosjava/android_apps/commit/2b24f586cafde0986c7597b6d5f4f322f6625e43

---

Originally posted by [davidnunez](https://answers.ros.org/users/14746/davidnunez/) with karma: 11 on 2014-04-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1